# Is it a good idea to attach recommendation letters in a cold email to potential supervisors?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

Assume that it is appropriate to send an email to potential supervisors to inquire about a research program.

Is it a good idea to attach recommendation letters in the cold email? Or instead, should I write in the email that recommendation letters from my academic referees can be provided if it is requested?

Comment: Is this specific to Australia?

Comment: It could be @Buffy, but I don't want to limit this question to AUS/NZ as I am going to apply to some other programs (which suggest me to contact potential supervisors in advance as well)

Comment: What does a "research program" mean here? Do you want an internship/RAship; or Master's/PhD student positions?

Comment: I would assume it is for a PhD position (probably AUS/EU/UK style rather than US style, i.e. you get a position from a particular supervisor to do a particular project rather then get a position in a group of PhD students from a university and finding a project/supervisor is left until later)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Assume that it is appropriate to send an email to potential supervisors to inquire about a research program.

That's fine but...

> Is it a good idea to attach recommendation letters in the cold email?

If I were the supervisor in question, I wouldn't be interested in these letters. Everybody can come up with nice recommendation letters and they don't normally mean much if anything. Actually I'd prefer to not get them as any uninteresting line I don't have to read is a good thing.

> Or instead, should I write in the email that recommendation letters from my academic referees can be provided if it is requested?

Another completely uninteresting line, don't do that. Every university has a formal admission procedure and normally you will have to submit recommendation letters there. That you can provide them if needed goes without saying.

Answer (score 3):

My experience is quite different and might not be relevant, since it is not common in the US to apply through a professor. I'm assuming here that your situation is the opposite.

But, rather than sending the letters, especially in an initial contact, you could send the names and affiliations of your recommenders, saying that they will supply letters if asked.

My opinion on such things is that shorter emails are easier to deal with and respond to if there is any interest. You won't be accepted into a program based on an initial letter in any case.